# State and Country picklist scan result issue

Tags: visualforce, country-and-state

I have used the option "Scan your org" in State and Country Picklists to get the address list and customization list (VF and APEX used) in that list one VF page is showing up which is not using city, state and country anywhere but still it is showing up.

I may think that VF page is for Proposals and Opportunity is the lookup field on it and Account is lookup on Opportunity. Is this the reason the Vf page is showing up in scan result??

Comment: This question is really hard to follow. What do you mean when you say you scanned your org? What tool did you use to do so? What are you looking for?

Comment: Does the vf page source have the strings "state" or "country" anywhere, even if they're being used in a different context?

Comment: I have checked all the details and there don't have any strings "state" or "country" anywhere.